# Switching file system from private to public makes all inline image paths broken

Tags: media, files

I built a site with private file system initially, but now want to switch to public so that I can use performance enhancements like css and js minification as they are not available for private file systems.

The problem is that switching to public changes the file path and breaks all the inline image paths. Any ideas how to do this properly?

Just as an example, with private file system paths show as
mysite.com/system/files/myfile.jpg
this is what was stored by the body field for inline images. These change to
mysite.com/sites/default..../myfile.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no miracle for that, you've to replace all path in the database. Fortunately MySQL has a [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function that will be useful for you.

First, you've to find every table/field that can contain inline image, if you're using Drupal 6, you'll look at `node` and `node_revision` for Drupal 7 it's more something like `field_data_body` and `field_revision_body`.

And finally you have to apply this query (for Drupal 7)

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value = REPLACE(body_value, 'system/files/', 'files/');
```

Perhaps you should customize a query a little, but the main idea is there.

Comment: Appreciated!  I just found this as well http://www.drupalace.com/questions/how-to-fix-broken-image-paths-when-changing-download-method-from-private-to-public and http://drupal.org/node/258099

Comment: isn't it 'body_value' not 'value_body'?

Comment: @cybercampbell you're right, I edited my answer. Thanks for the notice.