# Image Gallery not loading random thumbnails

Tags: caching, media

This has been happening for... perhaps for years.

I have an image gallery here http://windwanderer.com/image

When I load any page of this gallery, only SOME of the thumbnails are loaded and the rest show the default text.

Which thumbnails load and which do not changes with each load. Try it, go to the link above and see which images are shown (you may need to scroll down) then click "reload" on your browser. Some of those that looked to be unavailable will be loaded and some of those that loaded correctly the first time will now appear as thought the image can't be found.

The error occurs in Firefox, Midori, and even Dolphin browser running on Android phone!! Haven't tested it with iexplorer.

I believe this problem may have persisted over an upgrade from Drupal 5.x to 6.x

My guess was that it had something to do with the cache. Here is what I have done:

- I've emptied it
- turned off page caching
- rebuilt the derivative images multiple times

... yet the problem persists.

I would really appreciate any help. Please be patient, though, as I don't sit at my computer every day and it may take me time to test solutions.

Cheers
Jesse

> SITE STATS: Drupal Version: 6.x-2.9 Image Gallery Version: 6.x-1.1 Was
>   using acidfree albums in 5.x but changed to image gallery (views) when
>   upgraded to 6.x The view states "Overridden Node view: image_gallery"
>   Views Version: 6.x-2.16 Was using image toolkit: "GD2 image
>   manipulation toolkit" but have just changed to "ImageMagick Toolkit"
>   in attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked out your site and all images showed up. It took some time, but all images did show up. Looking at it further, it appears that you have your file system set to private. Go to admin/settings/file-system/settings and change the Download method to public. If this is not an option, then I would look at implementing xsend in apache and installing the drupal module http://drupal.org/project/xsend

Unless you have some VERY good reasons to set your file system to private, I highly recommend using a public file system.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Yes I have it set to public and now all the images load, I'm sure they didn't before no matter how long I waited... :-? Anyway. When I try to change the filesystem from private to public it warns me not to change it once I've setup my site. Do you happen to know what might go wrong if I change it now? I.e. How much time do I need to set aside to fix it if something goes wrong? I'm guessing the amount of time it would take me to restore a backup or setup the site from scratch. Any tips?

Comment: This might help you out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/switching-file-system-from-private-to-public-makes-all-inline-image-paths-broken